# PNG image keeps getting cut off

Tags: html, css, image

A PNG image cuts off from the bottom.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrp3w.png)

```css
.loadMoreBtn-label {
    background-image: url(picture);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-size: 23px 23px;
    background-position: ;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: post your code so people can help you

Comment: A value is missing for `background-position`. Is that significant or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a div that has the size you want, setting its background image and applying the `background-size: contain;` property.

Plus you can manipulate the div when your loading is done without doing CSS stuff.

Something like this:

```css
.loadMoreBtn-label {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.loadMoreBtn-label #loading {
    display: block;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    background-image: url(picture);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```